# How to scale a model proportionally?

Tags: modeling

[Here is my model link：https://gentle-field-05667750f.3.azurestaticapps.net/assets/box.gltf](https://gentle-field-05667750f.3.azurestaticapps.net/assets/box.gltf)

[image]

The picture above is the incorrect stretching of the model after being scaled.

So what should be the correct approach?

Comment: Hello, your title should reflect your problem, as for your question, it's not clear what you want, if you scale your box it will scale the lids as well, of course, if this is what you mean, maybe scale the bottom part only?

Comment: How to relate the faces, for example, the height of the upper lid is half the length of the bottom lid, so that no matter how it is scaled, the proportion will always be correct.

Comment: I gave this question a down-vote because the title is meaningless and communicates nothing about the actual question.

Comment: I modified the question information again

Comment: If you scale the object in its entirety (as you do when using _Object Mode_) just on one axis with the lid faces opened at an angle, it would be **not proportional** if the lids would keep their edge lengths.

Answer (score 2):

Correct approach could be:

- model everything with real proportions in the first place
- go to edit mode and select the parts that need to retain proportions and move them instead of scaling
- in your case the model seems to be rigged, so you can select the armature, go to pose mode(<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>) and then just select appropriate bones and move them:

[image]

One trick I personally use is to use hook modifiers. If I need to have a lot of copies of the same object in different sizes, like a door or a window and need to keep the proportions of the frames, I go to edit mode and select each part and hook it to an empty( <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>  +  <kbd>H</kbd>  -> Hook to New Object), then parent those empties to the object so that I can select the object, select the hierarchy( <kbd>Shift</kbd>  +  <kbd>]</kbd> ) and duplicate linked( <kbd>Alt</kbd>  +  <kbd>D</kbd> ), then move the new object and then I only have to move the empties to adjust the size so I can skip going to edit mode and selecting only the parts that I need:

[image]

And you can also use the same approach for more complex cases where your objects have multiple "clumps" of geometry that need to retain proportions, but the object needs to be scaled uniformly, because you can select the empties and scale only their locations:

[image]

However this is not "the right way to do this" and it's just something I find convenient. It is possible to do the same in many different ways with various rigging techniques, so that's only an example.

Comment: Oh, the hook solutions are nice... never thought of that because I usually don't have to modifiy a large number of objects... but will definitely keep this in mind +1

Comment: It's also helpful, because you can reuse the data so even with few objects with dense geometry and only their dimensions differing this can help keep the file size/GPU memory usage smaller. It's also easy to use material or geometry nodes to adjust UV offsets per object to make them look unique. I like reusing data a lot :D .

Comment: How to make the bones in the animation automatically update after moving the bones？

Comment: If you are in Pose mode, the geometry should be deformed in real time as you adjust the bones. Since you shared your scene exported in GLTF format, I am not really sure what you have in Blender so I cannot advise.

Comment: I adjusted the bones in pose mode and the geometry deformed, but when I clicked the start button of the animation, the geometry changed back?

Comment: There are probably some keyframes set.

Comment: Modifying the height can move the bones. How to modify the length and width of the express box? @MartynasŽiemys

Comment: You can delete the armature and try the hook modifier method, if you are going to need to change the dimensions a lot, if it's one time, it will be easier to just move the parts in edit mode.

Comment: Moving mesh components is really basic stuff, so if you struggle with that it will be easier to just watch some beginner tutorials. Like [these](https://www.blender.org/support/tutorials/) for example. That's one efficient way to learn the stuff quickly.  There are loads of free tutorials online on using Blender. With basics it's just easier to watch some of them then asking. Video tutorials will be better, more complete and a lot easier to understand than an answer can be here. If you don't find the answers you seek in tutorials, BSE is great for that.

Comment: It is a dynamically sized express box that needs to be able to modify the length, width and height. @MartynasŽiemys , and the top lid needs to be animated.

Comment: It's possible to make a more sophisticated rig. I think it would be better to ask a new question detailing all the requirements and explaining what your situation and goal is and why in detail if you want help with that. Your current question does not specify detail like that, so I don't think it's possible for anyone to just guess what you want and provide the answer you are looking for.